# How do I perform a transform on an image using motion vectors as the source of the transformation?

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to use x264's motion estimation algorithm to correct motion in one picture relative to another one.

So, basically, I want to take two pictures quickly in a row using a cell phone camera, and combine these two pictures into one (for HDR photography). Between the time it takes to snap the two pictures, the camera will move a bit, so the second picture will not be from exactly the same perspective as the first one, and so I need to find a way to correct for motion in the second picture.

To do this I'm using `x264`, and encoding a video consisting of two frames that are the two pictures taken with the camera. I'm using the option `--bframes 0` so that `x264` will output one I-frame and one P-frame. The P-frame will contain motion vectors that map various macroblocks of the I-frame (first frame) to the P-frame (second frame). The motion vectors can be visualized as follows:

[image: Motion vectors]

[First frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFk9W.png)

I've tried summing all the vectors, and moving the second image along the resulting vector. But this only corrects in the middle of the image; the further out from the center the worse it becomes. This is, at least, caused by this method's inability to detect rotation.

So. Now I have a large number of vectors that are placed on different points in the 2D space of the picture in question. 
I know PIL has a [transform](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.transform) function, that I hope can be used to perform the actual transform.

But,

1. Which of the `transform` functions (`EXTENT`, `AFFINE`, `QUAD`, `MESH`, `PERSPECTIVE`) should I use, to achieve the transform that I'm looking for?
2. How do I calculate the parameters for this transform function from the bunch of vectors I have from the motion search estimation algorithm?